# cannot find the SPSite name space

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I am unable to find the name space for the `SPSite`

I have imported these so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Data;


namespace GrandPermission
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SPSite oSPSite = new SPSite("http://spdevserver:1002/");
        }
    }
}
```

And `SPSite` still has red line under it.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Spsite is part of the Microsoft.SharePoint namespace.  You've added a reference to it twice at the top, not sure if that would cause a problem.  What happens when you try `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite oSPSite = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("https://spdevserver:10002/");`?

Comment: @Robbert I tried and still has red line saying missing reference.

Comment: Did you actually add a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint in the references section of Visual Studio? Adding `using Microsoft.SharePoint;` isn't good enough.

Comment: @Robbert I added another screen shot showing all the references I have added, could you have a look?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error occurs since [SPSite class](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx) is a part of **Server** Side Object Model API:

> **Server Side Object Model** API could be utilized **only** on machine where SharePoint Server/Foundation is installed.

Since you are using *Client Object Model API* (referenced assembly in your project `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` is a part of [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585))  i would recommend to utilize this API.

So, the line:

```
SPSite oSPSite = new SPSite("http://spdevserver:1002/");  //SSOM
```

could be replaced with:

```
using(var ctx = new ClientContext("http://spdevserver:1002/"))
{
    var site = ctx.Site;
    //...
}
```

### References

- [Choose the right API set in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, you are missing a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint in your project's references. You only have a reference to the client dll.

If you're not finding it, make sure you're either developing on a SharePoint server, i.e. SharePoint is installed, or have a copy of the dll on your machine.  I've seen forum posts where someone copied the SharePoint dll from a SharePoint server to a local non-SharePoint development machine. However, I've never gotten that to work.  I've always installed SharePoint on a development server and ran Visual Studio from it.

Comment: I could not find the `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`. I looked all over but `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` was not there. If you can guide me to the right location I will accept the answer.

Comment: Are you developing on a SharePoint server?  What version of .Net are you using? 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Developing on SharePoint server? I think this might be the problem, but I do not know what you mean by "develop on SharePoint server". I am on Windows 7 desktop using visual studio 2013. `.net` 4.0, 64bit

Comment: would you happen to know the `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` file location after the SharePoint server is installed?

Comment: Should be in the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the assembly `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` into your references in order to use it. You can find this DLL on the SharePoint server that you're working with:

On `SharePoint 2013` it lives at:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI
```

And on `SharePoint 2010` it can be found at:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI
```