# How to get site admin or owner user info in SharePoint using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I've write a program to get site info in SharePoint,

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("ShareURL");
        Web site = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(site);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        ListCollection lists = clientContext.Web.Lists;
        clientContext.Load(lists);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (List list in lists)
        {
            if (list.NoCrawl || list.Hidden || list.BaseType.ToString() == "Survey")
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (list.BaseType.ToString() == "GenericList")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List : " + list.Title);
            }
            else if (list.BaseType.ToString() == "DocumentLibrary" && list.Title.ToString() != "Images")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Document : " + list.Title);
            }
        }
```

but now i need to get this site admin or owner user, e.g. Email, User name...

how can i get this?

Comment: if you want the get information about current user you can check this out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6c36915e-2848-42fb-b30f-8894a8944a2f/sharepoint-c-get-list-of-sites-on-which-user-has-permission-read-contribute-owner-admin?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: i can't use SPSite, I using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client 14.0.0.0

Comment: where can download SPSite reference dll file?

Comment: you can check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633604/cannot-find-the-spsite-name-space

Comment: I've try to download  SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK and install but still can find this dll

Comment: SPSite lives in Microsoft.SharePoint (Microsoft.SharePoint.dll). All of the failures beyond that are part of the cascade of a missing reference. You should also check which .NET Framework you're running. Most development is done under 4.0 at the moment (not client profile)

Comment: oh i can using SPSite now, but when i run it will error Microsoft.SharePoint.Library can not found

Comment: Hi  @Valkyriee
I has use Microsoft.SharePoint.dll but when i running program it will error, it will show Microsoft.SharePoint.Library can not found, how can i fix this?

Comment: Hey, have you looked at this article? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-problems-opening-documents-in-SharePoint-libraries-31329fa1-4ad0-47fc-95d8-bb0c5b12a536

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can display info for site admin. If you are an admin and you want to get your own data here's how you can easily do it from the client side.
Code:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
   var currentUser;
       function init(){
        this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
         this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
         currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
         this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
        this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

 function onQuerySucceeded() {
var lUser = currentUser.get_loginName();
var result = lUser.split("\\")[1];
document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = result;
document.getElementById('userId').innerHTML = currentUser.get_id();
document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title();
document.getElementById('userEmail').innerHTML = currentUser.get_email();
 }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
  }
```

```
    <div>Current Logged User:
         <span id="userLoginName"></span>
         <span id="userId"></span>
         <span id="userTitle"></span>
         <span id="userEmail"></span> 
     </div>
```

This will display the user info for any logged on user.